# regarding rhapsody stereotype compilation

Tags: rhapsody

I am developing a logic for Model Check (Naming convention violation) in IBM rhapsody. Here is my code sample.

```
override check(IRPModelElement ElementToCheck, IRPCollection FailedElements)
    {
        for(Object o : ElementToCheck.getStereotypes().toList())
        {
            **IRPStereotype streo = (IRPStereotype) o;
            if(streo.getName().equals("MCSupp"))**
            return true;
        }

        var res = ElementToCheck.name.contains("rbt_")  

        return res
    }

    override getMetaclasses()
    {
        return "UseCaseDiagram, ActivityDiagram, Statechart, SequenceDiagram, Timing Diagram, Class Diagram, StructureDiagram"
    }
```

So basically I do not want rhapsody to report a naming convention violation,if user uses stereotype <>, else it should  report naming convention violation.

Error at **BOLD** part of code :

Multiple markers at this line
- Use 'as' keyword for type casting.
- This expression is not allowed in this context, since it doesn't
   cause any side effects.
- The method streo(Class) is undefined

and

The method or field streo is undefined

Can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The return type is void.
You cannot return anything